# php documentor test errors

Tags: php

I'm new in phpdocs , after installing it in 2 ways pear and another one , I try to test it by the wizard but it gives me this error
Parsing Files ...

PHP Version 5.3.0
phpDocumentor version 1.4.3

Parsing configuration file phpDocumentor.ini...
   (found in C:/wamp/www/pear/PhpDocumentor/)...

done
Maximum memory usage set at 256M after considering php.ini...
using tokenizer Parser

Grabbing README/INSTALL/CHANGELOG

done

Tutorial/Extended Documentation Parsing Stage

done

General Parsing Stage

done

Converting From Abstract Parsed Data

Processing Class Inheritance

Processing Root Trees

Processing leftover classes (classes that extend root classes not found in the same package)
done processing leftover classes

Processing Procedural Page Element Name Conflicts

Sorting page elements...done
Formatting @uses list...done

creating tutorials/sample/docs/\media
copying tutorials/sample/docs/\media/layout.css
copying tutorials/sample/docs/\media/print.css
copying tutorials/sample/docs/\media/style.css
ERROR: nothing parsed

Answer (score 0):

phpDocumentor is ages old and I honestly think you would be better off using a newer documentation generator.
Try having a look at [a port](https://github.com/romanb/phpdoctor) of [phpdoctor](http://peej.github.com/phpdoctor/) to php 5.3 or [phpdox](https://github.com/theseer/phpdox).

Zend is using something called [DocBlox](http://www.docblox-project.org/). I haven't tried it, but it certainly looks nice (and won't go away anytime soon if Zend is using it).

Answer (score 0):

I had

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project>phpdoc -o HTML:frames:earthli,PDF:default:default -t ./docs -d
PHP Version 5.5.11
phpDocumentor version 1.4.4

Parsing configuration file phpDocumentor.ini...
   (found in c:\xampp\php\data/PhpDocumentor/)...

done
Maximum memory usage set at 256M after considering php.ini...
using tokenizer Parser

ERROR: nothing parsed
```

you need to specify the path of the scan -d ./

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project>phpdoc -o HTML:frames:earthli,PDF:default:default -t ./docs -d ./
```

BTW I use the older version (1.4.4) I wanted to save to pdf. In the new version 2. * there is no such template.